# Multiple clones of Windows 10 VM with same license

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, licensing, volume-license

I have some questions about Windows 10 license used on a VM.

There is a scenario:

1. By using VMWare I install Windows 10 on a VM.
2. I lincence installed OS with a new license.
3. I make clones of the VM.

**My first question is:** Am I permitted to run these VMs but not simultaneously? I'll be running only one VM at the time.

**My second question is:** If so what type of license (Home, Pro, Enterprise) is have to use for it?

I looked into Microsoft Product Terms document and found this line (3.4.2.1): Customer may run Windows software acquired through a volume licensing agreement on up to four Virtual OSEs locally on Licensed Devices. 
So according to the line, by satisfying the volume licensing agreement, I'm permitted to run up to four VMs at the time. It seems there is no limitation of having more clones of a one installation of Windows.

So there is my **my third question** concerning the line from the document mentioned above: Assuming a company has volume licensing agreement then the company is permitted to use up to 4 of available licenses to run 4 VMs (every VM licenced by one available license). Am I right?

Comment: Well did you actually acquire said licenses through volume licensing?

Comment: In given scenario I was assuming there is no volume license agreement and the standard FPP license is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question: With VMware Workstation, you can make a Windows 10 virtual machine with a Retail Windows 10 license and you can make a copy (or copies) and so long as you only run one virtual machine at one time, you can do this.

Second Question: I always use Windows 10 Pro because I find Home too limiting. You can use Enterprise if you wish but Pro should do.

Third Question:  Yes, you can work within the rules set out for Volume Licenses.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers.

Comment: Do you have what you want?

Comment: I've done what you advised and created a copy of licensed Win 10 VM image. Windows was activated by product key. When I mount the copied image and go into "Settings > Update & Security > Activation" then there it's shows that Windows is not activated. Also I've tried to make clones instead of copies before, but end up with the same outcome. To make new VM (from copied image) activated I have to do phone call activation which is annoying process. Is there any way to have Windows still activated after the copy/clone process? Or there is no way how to avoid phone call activation process?

Comment: Cloning to a new system requires re-activation. If the system has Internet it may activate itself, but phone activation is not uncommon.

Comment: You mentioned "If the system has Internet it may activate itself", could you tell me by what condition it will activete itself?

Comment: Windows will go looking to activate but if the cloned environment is different enough, it may require phone activation. I think what you see is fairly normal

Comment: OK. I thank you for your replies they were very helpful.

Comment: You may at this point wish to mark my answer above.